# Parse Compatibility and Security

Tags: javascript, rest, ssl, parse-platform

I am new to the Parse. I was going through the docs and some questions that have been answered. But there are still a few questions in my mind.

First of all, I have learnt that the Javascript SDK doesn't work on IE9 and IE8 if the website doesn't have an SSL certificate. Can we still use Rest API to work with those browsers without an SSL certificate?

And my second question is about Javascript and API/SDK key security. I know there were other questions about this but they were mostly suggesting checking for a valid session and limiting some actions for some users. But this still wouldn't stop a user from altering his/her own score(First gets my key and then requests for a session token. Finally makes another request to the scores class and adds himself/herself a million points?). How can I secure my app against such scenarios?

Thank you all for your time and your answers in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In regards to your question about Javascript and API/SDK key security, there's a limit to how much you can do. If you want your app/site to be able to post to Parse, then there is nothing to stop a user from doing the same.

Your best option is to look at Cloud Code, a Cloud Function could be used to verify information before saving, for example you could write a method that takes a `levelNumber`, `score`, `enemiesKilled`, `livesLost` and runs some checks to see if the score supplied is possible. It could be as simple as this:

```
// hidden knowledge only known by you, stored in your Cloud Function
var maxScorePerEnemy = 750;

if (score > (enemiesKilled * maxScorePerEnemy)) {
    // we have a cheater! CRUSH KILL DESTROY!
}
```

A more advanced option would be to create some code that creates a temporary token that must be included with the score. It might not stop everyone, but makes it just that little bit harder.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! I guess it's going to function well. BTW I have tried REST API with IE9 but it didn't work either. I guess I'm going to need an SSL certificate either way.

Comment: You can host HTML files (and other content) in your Cloud Code, then access that via https, e.g. https://myapp.parseapp.com and put that in an iFrame on a page for IE users.